# Why is the advanced filter control not working with IN filter type using Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have [advanced filter control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/11335694) in one of my dashboard. It's working fine with Starts with, Contains but not working with "In". I am passing value like `GANESH`, `RED` (I have all data in upper case) but it's not giving any result.

[Sample Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/71d7be60-a866-4b79-9028-f688b7f709b5)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use multiple [Search Box](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/9e9729dc-203f-4679-8e14-2958e28f405a/page/N7lSB) [Community Visualisations](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9206527) (for a full selection of the chart(s), click the [image: 3] icon on the toolbar and select [image: 4]):

**Data Tab**

- ***Column to search on***: `ItemName` (the field to search)
- ***Cross-filtering***: Select (☑) (this is needed to filter values in other charts, as they are searched using the Search Box)

**Additional Details on the Search Box**

- ***Case Insensitive***: A term such as `Red` could be found whether it's `reD`, `RED`, `red`, etc.
- ***Real-time suggestions***: Values are filtered while typing thus users do not need to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after searching

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/de7845c0-1362-4f2d-8b87-9af568aa1d1b) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19eNrdV6lf4S4O497bbIrdj8KOgJhjreQK_Ety3avYPQ/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]